# Set column value based on another column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains 4 columns:

```
ItemId, ItemPrice, DateFrom, DateTo
```

The table contains information about items, their prices and the day that the prices changed

for example:

[image: Before update]

What I want to do, is to fill the DateTo column so I know what for how long the price has lasted and if it still lasts

The results I expect:

[image: After update]

An important note is also that the count of the price changes is unknown, for some items it changes 3 times and for some it doesn't change at all and the price remains unchanged until this day.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view would be far better solution to this, as there's no need to have a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, and you can't persist a column with the value `GETDATE()` (thus you would have to update the value of `DateTo` at the start of every day). This will get you the result you are after:

```
CREATE VIEW YourView AS

    SELECT ItemId,
           ItemPrice,
           DateFrom,
           LEAD(DATEADD(DAY,-1,DateFrom),1,GETDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY DateFrom ASC) AS DateTo
    FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: This works exactly as I needed it to work, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @mjohansen . Please remember to mark the answer as a solution if so, so that others with the same/similar question know it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query - [Check it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/931240)

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE
(
        itemid INT,
        itemprice INT,
        DateFrom Date
)

INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (111,5000,'2018-01-01'),(111,8000,'2018-02-24'),(111,6000,'2018-03-12')

SELECT *,ISNULL(
        (SELECT top 1 DATEADD(day,-1,DateFrom) 
            from @tab t1 
            WHERE t1.itemid= t2.itemid
            AND t1.Datefrom > t2.Datefrom) , GETDATE()) AS DateTo 
FROM @tab t2
```

Comment: Doing `SELECT top 1` without `ORDER BY` makes no sense: it will give unpredictable (quasi-random) results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DateTo` of each record to "the *smallest* of all From-dates (for the same `ItemId`) that are bigger than its own `DateFrom`, minus 1 day".

And for those where it couldn't be found, set it to GetDate().

In SQL:

```
UPDATE PriceTable
SET    DateTo = (SELECT DATEADD(d, -1, MIN(DateFrom))
                 FROM   PriceTable P2
                 WHERE  P2.ItemId   = P1.ItemId
                 AND    P2.DateFrom > P1.DateFrom)
FROM PriceTable P1

UPDATE PriceTable
SET    DateTo = GETDATE()
WHERE  DateTo IS NULL
```

Or combined into one step:

```
UPDATE PriceTable
SET    DateTo = (SELECT ISNULL(DATEADD(d, -1, MIN(DateFrom)), GETDATE())
                 FROM   PriceTable P2
                 WHERE  P2.ItemId   = P1.ItemId
                 AND    P2.DateFrom > P1.DateFrom)
FROM PriceTable P1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create date_to  column on adhoc basic as you see. below

```
SELECT ItemId, ItemPrice, DateFrom,
DATEADD(day, 1, lead(DateFrom,1,getdate()))  
over (order by ItemId asc ,DateFrom asc) as date_to 
FROM tbl
```

You can update value as

```
UPDATE tbl T2 SET dateto= 
(SELECT 
DATEADD(day, 1, lead(DateFrom,1,getdate()))  over (order by ItemId asc ,DateFrom asc) 
FROM tbl T1 where T1.ItemId=T1.ItemId AND  T1.ItemId = T2.ItemId AND  T1.DateFrom = 
T2.DateFrom)
```

Answer (score -1):

For future add trigger who update `dateTo` on insert new row, now you must select previous value `DateFrom`

```
SELECT ItemId, ItemPrice, DateFrom,
 SELECT(DateFrom FROM tbl WHERE ItemId IN (
   SELECT TOP 1 ItemId FROM tbl WHERE tbl.ItemId = tbl1.ItemId 
     WHERE tbl.DateFrom < tbl1.DateFrom 
     ORDER BY tbl.DateFrom DESC)
) FROM tbl AS tbl1
```

Comment: This doesn't give the OP an answer; it gives them an idea. Also, how does this solve the problem when there is no next value? If the default value of `DateTo` is set to `GETDATE()` it'll be stale after (at most) 24 hours.

Comment: @Larnu updated answer, And it should add something like `IFNULL(_QUERY_, GETDATE())`

Comment: That query won't run I'm afraid; for example a subquery in the `SELECT` needs to be wrapped in paranthesis(`()`). It also doesn't cater the latest value and (a valid) query would result in 3 scans of the table; which seems a little over kill.

Comment: My mistake is that I give a solution hint for MySQL. And you can reduce the number of scans to 2, but then you are not sure about the correctness of the returned data

Comment: This is a SQL Server question, not MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I give a clue to the solution that works in most RDBMS and not only in SQL Server